# Echelon basis for modular forms $M_{2}(\Gamma_{0}(23))$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, modular-function

This is referring to Example 9.15 in William Stein's book 'Modular forms: a computational approach'.

In this example, we are to calculate the newform of weight 2 level 23 in $S_{2}(\Gamma_{0}(23))$. It starts by working out the Manin symbols $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$ and the matrix form of Hecke operator $T_{2}$. We find that $T_{2}$ has an eigenspace (ker($T_{2}-3$)) spanned by the Eisenstein series of level 23 weight 2, and the other ($V =$ker($T_{2}^{2}+T_{2}-1$)) corresponds to $S_{2}(\Gamma_{0}(23))$.

Then the algorithm goes on to projecting onto $V$, which get me confused when he says the following matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & -2/11\\
0 & 1 & -3/11
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has the first two columns being the 'echelon basis for $V$' and last column being 'echelon basis for the Eisenstein subspace'. I have looked through the related sections in the book and I am still confused about where this comes from, and how we may calculate such a matrix for general levels (say $N = 11,37,etc$).

Comment: In fact one get the matrix by applying $T_{2}^{2} + T_{2} - 1$ on the three basis vectors, and the numbers naturally follow. I believe that echelon basis is a non-standard terminology.